# Issue with fwrite and fread

Tags: c, binary, fwrite, fread

Having an issue with my fwrite() and fread() dealing with a binary file here is my source code, and towards the bottem are my read and write.  Right now it is returning 'jake' when I run it, and nothing else.  I was told to write a dump buffer function to deal with the binary characters. In addition here is the text file as well, I am writing to a blank file called info.bin.  PS I know that it is bad practice to save the zip as an int but this is what my professor is asking for.

File:

```
mike|203-376-5555|7 Melba Ave|Milford|CT|06461
jake|203-555-5555|8 Melba Ave|Hartford|CT|65484
snake|203-555-5555|9 Melba Ave|Stamford|CT|06465
liquid|203-777-5555|2 Melba Ave|Barftown|CT|32154
```

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define LINE 80
#define RECORDS 10


struct info{
  char name[100];
  char number[100];
  char address[100];
  char city[100];
  char state[100];
  int zip;
};

void dump_buffer(void *buffer, int buffer_size)
{
  int x;

  for(x = 0; x < buffer_size; x++)
  {
    printf("%c",((char *)buffer)[x]);
  }
}

int i, j, seeker;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  char *buffer;

  struct info input_records[RECORDS];
  int nrecs = 0;
  unsigned long fileLen;
  char line[LINE];
  FILE *fp = NULL;
  FILE *fpbin = NULL;
  FILE *fpread = NULL;



  if (argc != 2) 
  {
    printf ("ERROR: you must specify file name!\n");
    return 1;
  }
  /* Open file */
  fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");
  if (!fp) 
  {
    perror ("File open error!\n");
    return 1;
  }

  while (!feof (fp)) {
    fgets(line, sizeof(line),fp);
    char* tok =  strtok(line, "|");

    while(tok != NULL)
    {
      strcpy(input_records[nrecs].name, tok);
      tok = strtok(NULL, "|");
      strcpy(input_records[nrecs].number, tok);
      tok = strtok(NULL, "|");
      strcpy(input_records[nrecs].address, tok);
      tok = strtok(NULL, "|");
      strcpy(input_records[nrecs].city, tok);
      tok = strtok(NULL, "|");
      strcpy(input_records[nrecs].state, tok);
      tok = strtok(NULL, "|");
      input_records[nrecs].zip = atoi(tok);
      tok = strtok(NULL, "|");
    }
    nrecs++;
  }




  fpbin = fopen("info2.bin", "wb");
  if (!fp) 
  {
    perror ("File open error!\n");
    return 1;
  }

  for(i = 0; i < 4; i++)
  {

   fwrite(&input_records[i], sizeof(struct info), 200000, fpbin);

  }

  fclose(fpbin);



  fpread = fopen("info2.bin", "rb");



  fseek(fpread, 0, SEEK_END);
  fileLen = ftell(fpread);
  fseek(fpread, 0, SEEK_SET);

  buffer = (char *)malloc(sizeof(struct info));

  fread(buffer, fileLen, 1, fpread);


  dump_buffer(buffer, sizeof(buffer));

  fclose(fpread);

  fclose(fp);
  free(buffer);
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
fwrite(&input_records[i], sizeof(struct info), 200000, fpbin);
```

You just told `fwrite` to write `200000 * sizeof(struct info)` bytes to the file, starting at the address of `input_records[i]`. That accesses memory far beyond what has been allocated for `input_records`, the behaviour is undefined, but a segmentation fault is not unlikely. I'm actually surprised that apparently it didn't crash for you.

```
buffer = (char *)malloc(sizeof(struct info));

fread(buffer, fileLen, 1, fpread);
```

You're trying to read `fileLen` bytes into a buffer of size `sizeof(struct info)`. If `fileLen > sizeof(struct info)`, that is again undefined behaviour, and if `fileLen` is sufficiently larger, likely to crash.

You should let `fwrite` *one* object of size `sizeof(struct info)` each time, and you should allocate `fileLen` bytes for the buffer you read in (or read in chunks of size `sizeof(struct info)`). And you should check the return values of `fwrite` and `fread` to know whether they succeeded in writing/reading the desired data and handle failures appropriately.

```
fpbin = fopen("info2.bin", "wb");
if (!fp) 
{
```

You check the wrong `FILE*` here, and you don't check `fpread` at all.

Further, you pass the wrong count to `dump_buffer`,

```
dump_buffer(buffer, sizeof(buffer));
```

`buffer` is a `char*`, so `sizeof buffer` is the size of a `char*`, typically four or eight bytes. You should pass the allocated size of the buffer there.

And, when reading the original file,

```
while (!feof (fp)) {
    fgets(line, sizeof(line),fp);
```

`feof(fp)` only becomes true after an attempt to read was made when the end of the file has been reached, you should change your loop condition to

```
while(fgets(line, sizeof line, fp) != NULL) {
```

Finally, your tokenizing code will fail badly if the input file contains malformed data, or too long lines. You should also add checks there, so that you don't pass a `NULL` to `strcpy` or `atoi`.

Comment: +1, also worth noting that the `dump_buffer()` call passes `sizeof buffer`, where `buffer` is a pointer (most likely 4 or 8 bytes).

Comment: @netcoder Good spot, I _just_ noticed that too when running the modified programme (I got eight bytes worth of data from the buffer).

Comment: Thank you I'm going give this a shot when I get home.

Comment: With the help I was able to get the program to return the first line of my text file from a binary, I am going to try and get it to return all 4.  Not sure whats wrong but I am going to be burning the midnight oil for this one, thanks again!